# Error message with Oracle odbc while opening connection to database

Tags: c#, oracle, odbc

I have a method below. I am using odbc to communicate with Oracle. I actually do not have problems with other methods while deleting data and using select statements.

I kept getting the error message below when I hit the  cn.open() line.

Message = "ERROR [HYC00] [Oracle][ODBC]Optional feature not implemented.\r\nERROR [HY000] [Oracle][ODBC]MTS support not available, could not load ORAMTS.DLL"

Any ideas about how I can fix this?

```
            public int WriteToOracleDb(IList<ExcelData> mn)
                    {
                        int totalCount = 0;
                        string connect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconnect"].ConnectionString;

                        try
                        {
                            using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
                            {
                                string sqlIns = "insert into u_generic_data ( " +
                                        "businessunitcode, generic_job_id, row_status, row_message, customernumber," +
                                        "productcode, numbervalue1, numbervalue2, numbervalue3, numbervalue4" + "," +
                                        "values (" +
                                        ":businessunitcode, :generic_job_id, :row_status, :row_message, :customernumber" + "," +
                                        ":productcode, :numbervalue1, :numbervalue2, :numbervalue3, :numbervalue4" + ")";

                                OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection(connect);
                                OdbcCommand cmdIns = new OdbcCommand(sqlIns, cn);
                                cn.Open();

                                for (int i = 0; i < mn.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("businessunitcode", mn[i].BusinessUnitCode);
                                    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("generic_job_id", mn[i].GenericJobId);
                                    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("row_status", mn[i].RowStatus);
                                    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("row_message", mn[i].RowMessage);
                                    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("customernumber", mn[i].CustomerNumber);

                                    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("productcode", mn[i].ProductCode);
                                    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("numbervalue1", mn[i].NumberValue1);
                                    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("numbervalue2", mn[i].NumberValue2);
                                    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("numbervalue3", mn[i].NumberValue3);
                                    cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("numbervalue4", mn[i].NumberValue4); 
                                    cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    cmdIns.Parameters.Clear();
                                }

                                scope.Complete();
                                cn.Close();
                                totalCount = mn.Count();
                            }

                        }
                        catch(Exception ex)
                        {
                            //resModel.ErrorMessages = ex.Message.ToString();
                        }

                        return totalCount;
                    }
```

Comment: I believe the comma immediately before the `values` part of the `insert` statement should be closing parenthesis `)` instead.

Comment: Thanks I corrected that. This statement fixed my problem using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used **Oracle 19c** 32bit client. I really need to escalate to MSDTC with the TransactionScope using.

I recorded the work of my application with the Process Monitor tool. It shows me that the **SQORA32.DLL** (which is a part of the Oracle client) tries to load the oramts**18**.dll.
[image]

But the **bin** folder contains oramts**19**.dll.
I opened the SQORA32.DLL in a binary viewer and found that the 'oramts18.dll' was hardcoded.
[image]

I created a copy of the oramts19.dll and renamed it to the oramts18.dll. The error disappeared.

It looks like a bug in the Oracle 19c client :(

I installed the **Oracle 21c** 32bit client instead of 19c. All works fine here.

Comment: The Oracle ODBC team say that this was fixed in 19.10.